# Use where function in a Laravel Collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have a array config with designs and each design correspond to a main tag category but some designs have two main tags for example pokemon + game of thrones:

```
'b5u8ic66ywua' => array(
        'design_id'     => 'b5u8ic66ywua',
        'design_name' => 'choose dragon blanket',
        'main_tag'    => 'pokemon,game of thrones',
        'tags'        => array('pokemon','pixelart','game of thrones'),
        'article_owner' => '1426',

    ),
    'dx6nalh1bkk4' => array(
        'design_id'     => 'dx6nalh1bkk4',
        'design_name' => 'choose direwolf blanket',
        'main_tag'    => 'pokemon,game of thrones',
        'tags'        => array('pokemon','pixelart','game of thrones'),
        'article_owner' => '1426',

    ), 
    'ih91h1i77g9j' => array(
        'design_id'     => 'ih91h1i77g9j',
        'design_name'   => 'game of thrones pixelart',
        'main_tag'      => 'game of thrones',
        'tags'          => array('game of thrones','stark','jon snow','daenerys', 'danny','pixelart','game of thrones'),
        'article_owner' => '1426',

    ),

    'wolcf2m524nu' => array(
        'design_id'     => 'wolcf2m524nu',
        'design_name'   => 'starks revenge',
        'main_tag'      => 'game of thrones',
        'tags'          => array('game of thrones','stark','house stark','starks'),
        'article_owner' => '1426',

    ),
```

In this case, I want get all designs that contains the main tag as game of thrones, and create a collection with these designs.

I´m using where function. For example, category_design_name in this case is 'game-of-thrones':

```
$family_article_designs = collect(config('artdesigns.'.$article_id))->where('main_tag',str_replace("-", " ", $category_design_name));

$family_article_designs = $family_article_designs->all();
```

This return me the designs with only main_tag=game of thrones, but not return me the designs with more than one main_tag:

```
'ih91h1i77g9j' => array(
        'design_id'     => 'ih91h1i77g9j',
        'design_name'   => 'game of thrones pixelart',
        'main_tag'      => 'game of thrones',
        'tags'          => array('game of thrones','stark','jon snow','daenerys', 'danny','pixelart','game of thrones'),
        'article_owner' => '1426',

    ),

    'wolcf2m524nu' => array(
        'design_id'     => 'wolcf2m524nu',
        'design_name'   => 'starks revenge',
        'main_tag'      => 'game of thrones',
        'tags'          => array('game of thrones','stark','house stark','starks'),
        'article_owner' => '1426',

    ),
```

I want get all the designs, that contains in his the word 'game of thrones'.

EDIT:

```
$family_article_designs = collect(config('artdesigns.'.'@'.$article_id))->filter(function ($value, $key) {
                            if(strpos($value['main_tag'], str_replace("-", " ", $category_design_name)) !== false)
                             return true;
                        });
```

This return me: **Undefined variable: category_design_name**

Comment: I think using `filter` with a callback would solve your problem. `collect(..)->filter(function ($value) { if(strpos($value['tags'], 'game of thrones') !== false) { return true; } else { return false; } })`

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I edit the main post with your answer

Comment: You're missing the `use` language construct to import variables. Variable scope hits again. https://secure.php.net/variables.scope `function ($value) use ($category_design_name) { ...` https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use variable name:

```
$family_article_designs = collect(config('artdesigns.'.'@'.$article_id))->filter(function ($value, $key) use($category_design_name) {
    if(strpos($value['main_tag'], str_replace("-", " ", $category_design_name)) !== false)
     return true;
});
```